# Website background - horizontally repeating, vertically scaling

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

Currently I'm working on one website and I have an unusual assignment. I need to set up an image as a website background and that image should be repeating itself in the horizontal direction but scaling in the vertical one.

I don't think that it is possible using just CSS, but it might be possible with jQuery? I think so, but I don't know how to do it.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the dimensions of the background image this is easy to do with CSS. In my example I have an image of 25px wide:

```
.background {
  background: url(http://placekitten.com/25/25) top left repeat-x;
  background-size: 25px 100%;
}
```

The `repeat-x` makes the image repeat horizontally. The background size sets an image width of `25px` and a height of `100%`, stretching it across the entire height of the div.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/vc6HV/